# Como intercambiar el valor de un FloatField a un CharField(Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, aplicación-web

Les comento lo mejor que pueda, en la DB de mi web tengo 2 opciones, una para poner un precio manualmente(FloatField) y otra que podes elegir entre varias predeterminadas(CharField) lo que busco hacer es que si uno de los dos está vació tome el lugar del otro, me mencionaron sobre Coalesce y intenté esto:

```
Coalesce('pricing', 'choicePrice')
```

Pero no me funcionó, lo que hace directamente es que como el campo (FloatField) está vació lo rellena con un 'None'...
Como puedo hacerlo? necesito ayuda... Y gracias de antemano, perdón si no me sepa explicar bien...

Models.py
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Index.html de la parte del form donde aparece el pricing:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el campo `FloatField` es rellenado y el `CharField` esta vacio, quieres que el valor del campo `FloatField` sea también el valor del campo  `CharField`  y viceversa? (también adjunta tus modelos, para que sea mas fácil la ayuda)

Comment: Quiero que tome el lugar del otro, si FloatField está vació y CharField no está, que el CharField tome el lugar de FloatField y viceversa

Comment: Quieres que tome su lugar, pero en el HTML?

Comment: Exactamente, el precio es imprimido en HTML, y si elijo una de las dos, que se imprima en HTML el correspondiente

Comment: Era de que hubieras aclarado este aspecto en tu pregunta desde un principio xD, acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo puedes usar el [**template tag `if`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

```
{% if product.pricing %}
    <span>{{ product.pricing }}</span>
{% else %}
    <span>{{ product.choicePrice }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

De esta manera, si el valor del campo `pricing` es valido, es decir si no esta "vacio", pues lo mostrara, caso contrario mostrara el valor del campo `choicePrice`. Cabe recalcar que estoy asumiendo que **solo uno de los campos puede estar vació.**

Comment: He hecho eso y no funcionó, sigue apareciendo None en lugar de estar puesto el otro, y al respecto de los dos campos, cualquiera de los dos puede estar vacío, pero uno de los dos tiene que tener algo

Comment: Por eso, estoy asumiendo que uno de los dos debería tener algo. Por otra parte, si te sale `None` **significa que los dos campos están vacíos...**

Comment: Te dejo una imagen de que no lo está...
https://imgur.com/6PpiEck

Comment: Disculpa, mi error, me olvidé cambiar a choicePrice, me funcionó, gracias

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte xD